# BERT: Weights of input embeddings as part of the Masked Language Model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, transformer-model, language-model

I looked through different implementations of BERT's Masked Language Model.
For pre-training there are **two** common versions:

1. Decoder would simply take the final embedding of the [MASK]ed token and pass it throught a linear layer (without any modifications):

```
    class LMPrediction(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, hidden_size, vocab_size):
            super().__init__()
            self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size, bias = False)
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(vocab_size))
            self.decoder.bias = self.bias
        def forward(self, x):
             return self.decoder(x)
```

2. Some implementations would use the weights of the input embeddings as weights of the decoder-linear-layer:

```
    class LMPrediction(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, hidden_size, vocab_size, embeddings):
            super().__init__()
            self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size, bias = False)
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(vocab_size))
            self.decoder.weight = embeddings.weight ## <- THIS LINE
            self.decoder.bias = self.bias
        def forward(self, x):
             return self.decoder(x)
```

Which one is correct? Mostly, I see the first implementation. However, the second one makes sense as well - but I cannot find it mentioned in any papers (I would like to see if the second version is somehow superior to the first one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are interested, it is called **weight tying** or **joint input-output embedding**. There are two papers that argue for the benefit of this approach:

- [Beyond Weight Tying: Learning Joint Input-Output Embeddings for Neural Machine Translation](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W18-6308/)
- [Using the Output Embedding to Improve Language Models](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/using-the-output-embedding-to-improve)